# Bootstrap scrollspy, want hyperlink on dropdown-toogle anchor tag and respective content need to show in container

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi my requirement for using bootstrap scrollspy is different as what we have by default functionality for dropdown-toggle anchor tag.

My navigation is top fix and having following structure

```
Home   - [ Home text matter]
About  - [ About text matter]
  |-- Mission -------- [ About Mission text matter]
  |-- Vision -------- [ About Vision text matter]
  |-- Team -------- [ About Team matter]
Product - [ Product text matter]
  |-- Product 1 -------- [ Product 1 text matter]
  |-- Product 2 -------- [ Product 2 text matter]
```

**As per by default bootstrap I can't put #about and #product to the navigation, if I am doing then my scrollspy is not working **

I want to add #about and #product to the navigation so I can show respective content. And sub menu options also show in the navigation when I am doing mouseover on about and product main menu.

Also as per above requirement if I'm accessing my menu on mobile than on 1st tab on About -> About content & About sub menu need to show and on 2nd tab on About -> About sub menu need to disappear. Same action require for product menu label.

[I am sharing my JSFiddle script, Kindly help me](https://jsfiddle.net/animatorstar/tgaa5agL/7/)

```
https://jsfiddle.net/animatorstar/tgaa5agL/7/
```